# Returning random rows that are evenly spread over a grouping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am creating some Examination Software where I have to pick random questions for each student, with a specific number of questions from each Subject's Chapter.

So for example, the Maths subject is divided into 12 Chapters and I want 50 random questions with at least 3 questions from each chapter.

I have the following query so far which is giving me 50 random questions.

```
SELECT TOP 50 Q.ID, Q.Subject_name, Q.Chapter 
FROM  Questions Q 
WHERE 50 >= RAND() * (SELECT MAX(25) FROM Questions Q)
```

Comment: He wants a random set of 50 rows/questions, with at least 3 from each chapter. It's pretty clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**ROW_NUMBER**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) to generate a sequential number for each question per chapter. On top of this, to get random rows you can generate a [**NEWID**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) for each row that can be used to order the rows:

```
SELECT TOP 50 Q.ID, Q.Chapter , 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Chapter ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Row
FROM questions Q
ORDER BY Row
```

Each time this is run, you will get 50 random rows, that are spread over the chapters evenly.

### [Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a022e/2)

Comment: Using order by (ROW_NUMBER) is a really nice way to get the requested weighting.

Comment: Thanks. It's the best method I could come up with. Nice little challenge :-)

Comment: @Tanner: This will not guarantee 3  questions from each chapter. It only delivers 50 random questions from a random chapter, they could theoretically all belong to the same chapter.

Comment: @Quandary care to explain why you believe your statement to be true? I'm pretty confident it works.

Comment: thanks Tanner a lot for ur help. I have just crashed my server. wasn't able to test your code. As soon as i get the server back, will reply you, thanks again.

Comment: @JamshaidRiaz no problem, let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: @Tanner: I was wrong. But you're query is still wrong. It does not do what either of us thought it does. I added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: @Quandary I've managed to get it working by editing the query to add newid() into the rownumber() order by, thanks

Comment: @Tanner: Looks good now. I completely neglected to consider that it will begin to recount at 1 by random order when the chapter changes.) The union was completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Tanner, hey Tanner thanks a lot man, I have got exact result as i wanted to. suprb Help.

Comment: @JamshaidRiaz no problem, I see this is your first question. Please have a read of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work, which will tell you how voting and accepting an answer works on the site.

Comment: Thanks @tanner again for teaching the way this website is used.

Comment: @Quandary it now works because all Tanner did was selecting a random first, radom second, etc question on each chapter and after it getting the top 50 questions ordered by position (all first + all second+...) if you order by Rows, chapter it's more easy to see it